# How to load data of home page in spring mvc

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, controller

I have home page which contains features like city,country,states, user details and some pie charts and diagrams representing the data anlysis of the user.I am new to spring mvc  I am in a confusion whether I should load the data of home page in one go or I should have onclick calls which would call to my controllers and load the data.

```
    Example:
    MyController Class
    public class HomeController {

        @Autowired
        private EngagaementService engagaementService;

        @Autowired
        private EmployeeService employeeService;

        @Autowired
        private CgOfficeDetailsService cgOfficeDetailsService;



        @RequestMapping("/")
        public ModelAndView handleRequest() {
            List<EmployeeInfo> listEmployees = employeeService.listEmployeeInfos();
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
            model.addObject("emp", listEmployees);
            model.addObject("empCount", listEmployees.size());
            return model;
        }

        @GetMapping("/getCity")
        public ModelAndView getBU(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String country = "India";
            List<String> buList = employeeService.getCityName(country);
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
            model.addObject("buList", buList);
            return model;
        }

        @GetMapping("/getState")
        public ModelAndView getState(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String country = "UP";
            List<String> buList = employeeService.getState(country);
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
            model.addObject("buList", buList);
            return model;
        }

        @GetMapping("/getUsers")
        public ModelAndView getUsers(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String country = "UP";
            List<String> buList = employeeService.getState(country);
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
            model.addObject("buList", buList);
            return model;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of permissions. I'd like to design my app architecture so that all the data that is accessible with current / particular authorization level (so to speak) is available on demand.

And if so, (I assume that's your case, since I don't see any further authentication in your code) it's only the question of your view design (frontend design).